# Can I automatically derive some instances like Equatable?

Tags: swift

Say I have a struct where all the memebers already are `Equatable`.

```
struct S {
  let a : String
  let b : Int
  let c : Double
}
```

Would anyone know of any way to automatically make `S` equatable without manually and boringly defining `==`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you'll have to define it manually:

```
func == (l: S, r: S) -> Bool { return l.a == r.a && l.b == r.b && l.c == r.c }
```

That's about as short as you can make it. But it's pretty darn short (one line!), its meaning is clear, and it's ready for future complications you may add to your type. Be happy!

Comment: I'm familiar with some other languages like Haskell where you are able to automatically get equality of 'something' if everything that this 'something' is made up of is also equatable. I hope this feature makes it into Swift one day!

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 4.1, Types will now synthesize conformance to `Equatable` and `Hashable` if all of the Type's members conform to the protocol.

If all of the type's properties are `Equatable`, simply define your Struct as `Equatable` and the required equality methods will be synthesized.

```
struct S: Equatable {
    let a : String
    let b : Int
    let c : Double
}
```

> Proposal: SE-0185
> Status: Implemented (Swift 4.1)
>
> Developers have to write large amounts of boilerplate code to support equatability and hashability of complex types. This proposal offers a way for the compiler to automatically synthesize conformance to `Equatable` and `Hashable` to reduce this boilerplate, in a subset of scenarios where generating the correct implementation is known to be possible.
>
> https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md